# Force divs within table columns to have the same height as column with CSS

Tags: css, html-table, multiple-columns

[Here's my example.](http://jsfiddle.net/LUah8/2/)

If you have two table columns, one with taller content than the other, then divs inside the other column don't expand to the first column's, even with `height:100%`. How can I create this behavior with CSS?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">
            <ul>
                <li>fasdf</li>
                <li>asgasdf</li>
                <li>afdsaggrea</li>
                <li>asgasdf</li>
                <li>afdsaggrea</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="two">
            <div class="three">
                First div
                <div>
                    Second div
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i.e. in my [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LUah8/2/), the behavior I want is the green box filling the entire yellow box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your div wont grow when you assign it a height of 100% is that the parent doesn't have a height.

ie. You have a list that is causing the table to grow larger.

To remedy this, you can add a height to the parent cell and give the child a height of 100% as shown [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUah8/4/)

```
.two{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100px;
}
.three{
    background-color:green;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my question. The heights can't be fixed, since the two columns hold dynamic content. The table, rows, and columns must have heights that depend on their content.

Comment: The heights can be anything, there just has to be something there so when you declare a height of 100% it will grab it.

You could declare a height of 1px and the child div would still inherit the height of the largest table cell. http://jsfiddle.net/LUah8/5/

Comment: WHOA. That is an incredible insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add oveflow auto as well.

```
.three {
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

It will work in some smart browsers like chrome. But it will be an issue in others because the parent doesnt have a known height at the time of rendering. 
You can set height to your .two class  and then height and overflow properties in .three class should fix your problem.

Or use javascript :)

Comment: Good find- this works in webkit browsers, but not Firefox :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to set a concrete height, and you want it to work in all browsers, I added a nicely coded javascript solution to your [***forked JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/3VK7A/).

```
var tableCritter = new function TableCritter(){
  var critter=this;
  var $window = $(window);
  var $two = critter.$two = $('.two');
  var $three = critter.$three = $('.three');

  function adjustHeight(){
    $three.css({ height:$two.height() });
  }; 
  adjustHeight();
  $window.on('resize',adjustHeight);

  critter.stop = function(){
    $window.off('resize',adjustHeight);
  };
};
```